# input.value is destroyed after swapping <li> items in places

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a simple ul with list items that contain few buttons. Two buttons are navigational they suppose to move list items either forward or backward.

The problem is: whenever I click Previous or Next button, the text in the list item  disappears. Moreover, additional edit button adds up after each click.

Is there a way to preserve the text in list items after they get swapped in places?

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');
const ul = document.querySelector('ul');
const listItem = document.querySelector('li');
const addItemInput = document.querySelector('input.add-item-input');
const addItemButton = document.querySelector('button.add-item-button');
const removeItemButton = document.querySelector('button.remove-item-button');

function attach_span(li) {
 const span = document.createElement('span');
 span.textContent = addItemInput.value;
 li.appendChild(span);
}

function attach_br(li) {
 const br = document.createElement('br');
 li.appendChild(br);
}

function attachButton_previous(li) {
 const prev = document.createElement('button');
 prev.className = 'previous';
 prev.textContent = 'Previous';
 if(li.previousElementSibling) li.appendChild(prev);
}

function attachButton_remove(li) {
 const remove = document.createElement('button');
 remove.className = 'remove';
 remove.textContent = 'Remove';
 li.appendChild(remove);
}

function attachButton_edit(li) {
 const edit = document.createElement('button');
 edit.className = 'edit';
 edit.textContent = 'Edit';
 li.appendChild(edit);
}

function attachButton_next(li) {
 const next = document.createElement('button');
 next.className = 'next';
 next.textContent = 'Next';
 li.appendChild(next);
}

function attachListItems(li) {
 attach_span(li);
 attach_br(li);
 attachButton_previous(li);
 attachButton_remove(li);
 attachButton_edit(li);
 attachButton_next(li);
}

addItemButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
 const li = document.createElement('li');
 ul.appendChild(li);
 attachListItems(li);
 addItemInput.value = '';
});

removeItemButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
 const ul = document.getElementsByTagName('ul')[0];
 const li = document.querySelector('li:last-child');
 ul.removeChild(li);
});

ul.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
 if(e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON' ) {
  const button = e.target;
  const li = button.parentNode;
  const ul = li.parentNode;
  const prevEl = li.previousElementSibling;
  const nextEl = li.nextElementSibling;
  if(button.className === 'remove') {
   ul.removeChild(li);
  }
  if(button.className === 'previous') {
   if(prevEl) {
    ul.insertBefore(li, prevEl);
   }
  }
  if(button.className === 'next') {
   if(nextEl) {
    ul.insertBefore(nextEl, li);
   }
  }
  if(button.className === 'edit') {
   const span = li.firstElementChild;
   const input = document.createElement('input');
   input.type = 'text';
   input.value = span.textContent;
   li.insertBefore(input, span);
   li.removeChild(span);
   button.className = 'save';
   button.textContent = 'Save';
  } else {
   const input = li.firstElementChild;
   const span = document.createElement('span');
   span.textContent = input.value;
   li.insertBefore(span, input);
   li.removeChild(input);
   button.className = 'edit';
   button.textContent = 'Edit';
  }
 }
});
```

```html
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.6.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-UHRtZLI+pbxtHCWp1t77Bi1L4ZtiqrqD80Kn4Z8NTSRyMA2Fd33n5dQ8lWUE00s/" crossorigin="anonymous">
 <header></header>
 <article>
  <nav id="main-nav">
   <ul>
    
   </ul>
  </nav>

  <form class="form">
   <input class="add-item-input" name="itemInput" type="text" title="Input for menu items">
   <button class="add-item-button" type="button">Add item</button>
   <button class="remove-item-button" type="button">Remove last item</button>
  </form>
</article>


 <p id="spitResult"></p>
 
 <!-- <script src="js/functions.js"></script> -->
 <script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's not everything that goes wrong: Some buttons transmogrify into an 'Edit' button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54666371/list-item-text-disappears-after-insertbefore-previouselementsibling-or-inserting?rq=1).

Comment: I thought the previous post was over-explanatory. Deleted the previous one.